# how to fix 'expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(data)'

Tags: c++, class, doubly-linked-list

I am using a guideline to create a doublylinkedlist in the guide it tells me to use Node(data :const string&), however when I go to create the constructor for this it throws the 'error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before ‘(’ token doublylinkedlist::Node::Node(data)'

```
 #ifndef __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
 #define __DOUBLYLINKEDLIST_H__
//
//
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
template <class s>
class doublylinkedlist {

  public:
            doublylinkedlist();
            ~doublylinkedlist();
            void append (s& data);
            void insertBefore (s& data);
            void remove (s& data);
            bool empty();
            void begin();
            void end();
            bool next();
            bool prev();
            bool find(s& data);
            string data;
            const string &getData(){return data;}
    private:
            class Node
            {
                    public:
                    Node(const string &data){}
                    ~Node();
                    Node(s& data);
                    Node* next;
                    Node* prev;
                    string *data;
            };
            Node* head;
            Node* tail;
            Node* current;
};
template <class s>
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(data)
{
    this->data;
    this->next=nullptr;
    this->prev=nullptr;
}
```

Comment: Unrelated: Take care with underscores. They often mean special things. Discussion and explanation here: [What are the rules about using an underscore in a C++ identifier?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/228783/what-are-the-rules-about-using-an-underscore-in-a-c-identifier)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In

```
template <class s>
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(data)
{
    this->data; // whups! Something should be assigned here. this->data = data;
    this->next=nullptr;
    this->prev=nullptr;
}
```

`doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(data)` does not provide the  data type of `data`. It should be

```
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const string &data)
```

to match the declaration.

That's the bug you're currently seeing. But wait! There's more!

`doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const string &data)` was not just declared in the class, it was accidentally defined! It need to lose the curly braces.

```
Node(const string &data){}
```

Must become

```
Node(const string &data);
```

Otherwise the compiler will find two implementations of the constructor and fail.

But that doesn't really make sense. The node should be storing `s`, not `string`, 
so

```
Node(const s &data){}
```

really needs to be

```
Node(const s &data);
```

and

```
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const string &data)
```

must be

```
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const s &data)
```

Side notes:

It's recommended that you do not use `using namespace std;`. [Explanation here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). You should never use it at global scope in a header because any file that includes the header could now be in for a very nasty surprise.

In addition

```
Node(const s &data);
```

could become

```
Node(const s &data): data(data), next(nullptr), prev(nullptr){}
```

and eliminate the need for

```
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const s &data)
```

entirely. The `:` starts up a [Member Initializer List](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/initializer_list), a tool that is greatly under-taught considering it's importance.

Repeating the same variable name in the same scope is called Shadowing. Don't do it unless you can't find an alternative (you always can) because it because it confuses people. They can easily get the two `data` variables screwed up.

Answer (score 0):

The user-defined constructor declaration and definition should match. The `data` in the constructor definition does not have a type.
Your constructor should be like this:

```
template <class s>
doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(s& data)
{    
    this->next=nullptr;
    this->prev=nullptr;
}
```

The below line does not do anything. So it can be removed. Or assigned with the `data` argument.

```
this->data; // this->data = data; ??
```

Also `using namespace std;` within the header file is considered bad practice and can even cause bugs.
See this post: [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice)

Comment: I've tried that but I get the error "error: candidate is: doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(const string&)" and the error "error: prototype for ‘doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(s&)’ does not match any in class ‘doublylinkedlist<s>::Node’ doublylinkedlist<s>::Node::Node(s& data)"

Comment: @PW it works because the template was never used, never expanded, and never compiled in your example.

Comment: @user4581301: Did not know how the OP was using the template. Would have been good to have an example from the OP.

Comment: @PW Agreed. Many things wrong in the code. You solved the one they asked about.